# Maven Javascript Compressor

Tags: javascript, maven-2, minify

I want to know how one can compress javascriptfiles using maven. 
I have lready visited webistes like 
http://mojohaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/guide-webapp-development.html
 but there is no implementation explained.

I want to know the dependency for executing the maven plugin.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using the [YUI Compressor Maven Mojo](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/index.html) and its [`yuicompressor:compress`](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html) goal instead. It is well documented, it just works.

To use it, add the following `pluginRepository`:

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <name>oss.sonatype.org - github-releases</name>
      <id>oss.sonatype.org-github-releases</id>
      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

And declare the plugin:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.9</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compress</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>   
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Refer to the [Usage](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/usage_compress.html) page and the parameters of [yuicompressor:compress](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html) for precise configuration.

Comment: Hello Pascal, 
Thank you for replying and giving the solution. The plugin works fine for me and I can compress the files required for the project. In the mean time I have 2 more related questions. Original yuicompressor was capable of removing new line for JS file. Is there way that I can remove new line from the compressed js using the plugin ? 
e.g. 
test.namespace("com.grid");
com.grid.Menu=function(a){this.m_oMenu=new com.grid.Menu(a,this);
this.m_oMenu=a;
};

As a single line 
test.namespace("com.grid");com.grid.Menu=function(a){this.m_oMenu=new com.grid.Menu(a,this);this.m_oMenu=a;};

Comment: @AmbGup I don't know, I'm not a hardcore user of this plugin. But it looks like the plugin removes unnecessary semicolumn by default. Maybe this should be turned off (using `preserveAllSemiColons`) so that it can remove new lines.

Answer (score 4):

The best and the most advanced one I found till today is [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/). The idea for the library and the Maven plugin is different from everything I was able to find on the internet, combining pretty much every tool available into one standalone library. Amazing.

You have two modes with [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) available - first is to operate dynamically as a filter in Java application, second is to use build-time solution with Maven plugin. It's all really straightforward and well explained on the project [documentation section](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/GettingStarted), so take a look and dive deep. There are fully operational and well explained examples on how to integrate [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/) with one's application or with Maven build process.

Comment: Wow...just wow. I was about to spend the week replicating this library (well, a lot more than a week if I implemented all of the supported features it has).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [cactus maven plugin](https://github.com/nbabinski/Cactus)