# YUI compressor compress and replace on build

Tags: java, javascript, maven, yui

I was trying to find the `js/css` compressing tool for the maven project, so I found this thread - [Maven Javascript Compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586455/maven-javascript-compressor)

It works all fine, but there is one issue I'm still trying to figure out.

When you don't set the suffix the yui, it sets `*-min` by default and creates a new file right by the old one. So, for example if I had `scripts.js` after the maven build with that plugin I will have both `scripts.js` and `scripts-min.js` files. I need just the `*-min` file. If I set the `<nosuffix>` to true, it sais that the compression was successful, but it doesn't override the file.

Is there a way I could have only the compressed files with the same name?

Comment: Maybe change output directory to another?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good, but still, the source file remain.. I was thinking of an ant script..

Comment: Something like that? https://gist.github.com/93819e34f56200163767

Comment: Not so complex. Just a simple ant copy task with delete after the copying.

Comment: This is just a simple copy task? Have a look at the comments!

Comment: I think so.. the `scripts-min.js` code copy to `scripts.js` and then delete the `scripts-min.js`

Comment: ```move /Y script-min.js script.js```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing this ant script for the maven ant plugin:

```
<delete includeEmptyDirs="false">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/js" excludes="**/*-min.js" />          
</delete>
<move todir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/js" includeemptydirs="false">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/js" />
    <mapper type="glob" from="*-min.js" to="*.js" />
</move>

<delete includeEmptyDirs="false">
<fileset dir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/css"
    excludes="**/*-min.css, **/*.ttf, **/*.png, **/*.jpg" />
</delete>
<move todir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/css" includeemptydirs="false">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}/resources/css" />
    <mapper type="glob" from="*-min.css" to="*.css" />
</move>
```

Brief explanation: the script first deletes the old not-compressed files and then renames the `*-min.js` and `*-min.css` files to simply `*.js` and `*.css`

Works fine, just tested. Also, if you have some different files in the `/js` or `/css` folders (not `.js` or `.css`), make sure you don't have them deleted and put those extentions in the `exclude` property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,the maven Javascript Compressor that you are using did compressing the files.
But during **maven package lifecycle**,the compressing happend during the phase **prepare-package**,After that,during the **package phase**,the maven-war-plugin will copy the orginal files and override what the compressor just did.
The configuration below is how I solve the problem,I compress the js files to another folder,and copy it back during package phase.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>yui-compress</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*-min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*-min.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/amazeui*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                <statistics>false</statistics>
                <linebreakpos>5000</linebreakpos>
                <useSmallestFile>true</useSmallestFile>
                <jswarn>false</jswarn>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/web</warSourceDirectory>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/min</webappDirectory>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}/min</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```