# How to compress and optimize Javascripts in Maven build process?

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm interested is there a way to compress and optimize Javascripts and CSS in Maven build process? Can I for example use Maven plugin or external script which do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may refer to [Maven Javascript Compressor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586455/maven-javascript-compressor), especially the [yuicompressor-maven-plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/).

> **Compress (Minify + Ofuscate) Javascript files and CSS files** using [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/) from Julien Lecomte. Because Javascript compression could need time and resource, and to avoid repetitive (stupid) resources consumming at runtime, this plugin do compression of static files at compile time .

Anyhow you may interesting about [javascript-maven-tools](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-maven-tools/)

> **JavaScript Compressor Maven Plugin**
>   Flexible JavaScript source compression using the YUICompressor as compression backend.
>   Selective bundle generation with compression capability.

I hope this may help.